# Webpack output to es5 / es6?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Is it possible have webpack output multiple ECMAScript versions?

Something like:

- bundle5.js
- bundle6.js

**EDIT:**

What I mean, is wether Webpack can create both variants in one single run.

Comment: I’m pretty sure all ES5 code _is_ ES6 compatible. They are just standards by the way. So if you need ES5, DONT output ES6.

Comment: @Socrates Have you found a way to achieve this? And if you found a way, could you write it down as answer. I need to achieve this as well.

Comment: @PEIN Nope, I could not find any way to achieve this. Still looking for a solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one pass, I'm not sure you can do it with webpack.
But you can export multiple targets using an array of configurations.

If you use babel 7, you can do something like this (untested):

```
module.exports = [
  {
    output: {
      filename: './dist-bundle-es5.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    forceAllTransforms: true
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    name: 'es5',
    entry: './app.js'
  },
  {
    output: {
      filename: './dist-bundle-es6.js'
    },
    name: 'es6',
    entry: './app.js'
  }
];
```

Check: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations

Edit: add example

Comment: Please include the relevant info in your answer.